# SQL - join 2 filtered and grouped time series

Tags: sql, presto

I have 2 SQL queries that I'm trying to run with Presto/AWS Athena and they look a bit like this:

```
SELECT count(distinct id) as filtered_id,
    date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(mydate), '%Y-%c') AS month_year
FROM table
WHERE value = 'bla'
GROUP BY  date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(mydate), '%Y-%c')
ORDER BY  date_parse(month_year, '%Y-%c')
```

```
SELECT count(distinct id) as unfiltered_id,
    date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(mydate), '%Y-%c') AS month_year
FROM table
GROUP BY  date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(mydate), '%Y-%c')
ORDER BY  date_parse(month_year, '%Y-%c')
```

I'd want to merge these results in a single table, basically a time series with 2 values for the respective dates. I'd want `filtered_id` and `unfiltered_id` to remain separate columns. I'm not sure how to achieve this, I've tried to join on the same table but I can't figure out how to filter just for 1 series.

Basically I want something like this as a result:

```
filtered_ids, unfiltered_ids, month_year
6, 15, 2020-06
10, 10, 2020-07
10, 20, 2020-08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT count(distinct case when value = 'bla' then id end) as filtered_id,
       count(distinct id) as filtered_id,
       date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(mydate), '%Y-%c') AS month_year
FROM table
GROUP BY  date_format(from_iso8601_timestamp(mydate), '%Y-%c')
ORDER BY  date_parse(month_year, '%Y-%c');
```

Comment: Oh, that did the trick. Do you have a good reference for conditional aggregation? I'm far from an SQL expert but it's the first time I encounter it.